# SSHFS mount that freezes system on network disconnect

Tags: sshfs, fuse

i am using SSHFS to mount a volume. But whenever anything causes a network disconnect or interruption my whole system will freeze up. Apps will be slow and unresponsive, and it is impossible for me to force eject the volume or shutdown. I have to hold down my power button to turn off my machine.

this is my connection

```
sshfs -o reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3,daemon_timeout=15,auto_cache,volname=devenv,defer_permissions,kill_on_unmount  root@192.168.1.31:/home/ /Volumes/Devenv
```

i am on OSX 11.3.1

Does anyone know what i can change to prevent it from freezing up my system?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try mounting it in a slightly less accessed location, a lot of apps and/or services will try listing the contents of /Volumes, which will freeze when the SSH tunnel failed.

That won't fix the FUSE filesystem itself but light help with the overall sluggishness.

Comment: Would like to know if there are updates on this issue.